# show Random display of dice image from drawable folder in Android while adding it's value

Tags: android, eclipse, image, random

To make my question clear, I have these dice images range from 1 to 4 which is imported on the `drawable folder`. What am trying to do is during the app's run on the emulator, the dices would show its original look:

ex.

figure 1:
[**.**] -image of dice one        [**..**] - image of dice two

underneath these two is a button named `play` so when the user click this button, the images for these dices will now be randomly changed.

figure 2:
[**...**] -from dice one to three   [**....**] - from dice two to four

It may sound simple by using `setimageresource` aside from it randomly changes, I need to add its value.

for example,

[**.**] - In my figure 1 above: dice one has originally a value of one. But when it suddenly changes to dice three in Figure 2 above, it now has the image of dice three and also a value of number 3.

same with dice two in my figure 1 above:

[**..**] it has a value of two, but when it changes to dice image 4, it now has an value of 4.

So 3+4=7. When the user clicks the `play` button not only the images randomly display new images of dice but it also adds its value and determine which number is the highest. In this example, 4 is the highest right? So this is only the time that the app would say who's the winner by a pop-up.

`toast.makeText(this,"You Win!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).Show();`

Below is my code in trying to do it:

`dice1=setImageResource(R.drawable.dice2s);` but this won't make the dice image display randomly.

Could you help me? Am sorry for my limited english. This one is quite hard to explain though. But I hope you do get my point. I really need somebody who can read behind `Android codes` and I hope its one of you.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you can use it:

```
    Random r = new Random();
    int num = r.nextInt(4);
    switch (num) {
        case 0:
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.0);
            break;
        case 1:
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.1);
            break;
        case 2:
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.2);
            break;
        case 3:
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.3);
            break;
    }
    coverImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: Thanks @Eliran so this is how I can randomize the dice images. but how about its value needed to be added? Shall I create a different `public void` to hold each dices value and then plus it when it appears? What do you think?

Comment: About the value you mean about int value for each image?